# How to get the information of the items in the cart? magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

I was trying to get the information of the items in the cart and got it using the code below, the problem is that I need to get a lot of other information. And when giving a var_dump($cart), it showed the cart information. As in this example I saw on the internet, "$item->getProduct()" is used to get the elements. How can I give a var_dump() inside the $item variable to find out the values ​​that are inside the item?

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote();
foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
    $productId = $item->getProduct()->getId();
    $productPrice = $item->getProduct()->getPrice();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this to get cart item.

```
$quote = Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getQuote();
$value = [];
foreach ($quote->getAllItems() as $item) {
$value[]= array (
 'id' => $item->getSku(),
 'quantity' => $item->getQty(),
 'price' => $item->getParentItemId()?  $item->getParentItem()->getPrice(): $item->getPrice()
  );
  }
```

Happy Coding. :)

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for the reply! But what I need is to know how I discover the modules that seek information. And already taking advantage of how would I get the image of the product that is in the cart?

Comment: You can check over this for image. https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92795/how-to-display-the-thumbnails-of-the-products-in-the-cart